# How ensure in Luquibase the order of changes on inter database level?

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

We have been using separate changelogs per each database for quite a while. But now I came across an issue. I want to make changes for two databases, where script for one database can be performed successfully only after another script's completing.

I tried to make it placing both changes in single log, but when running liquibase I come across "**changelog lock**" error.

ps. The removal of the lock in the database via this script didn't help.

```
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=0, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;
```

Comment: Would you please add a little more detail about the steps you normally take and the steps you are trying to take? I have a rough idea what you are attempting however don't know how you are trying to do it.

Comment: @CheeseFerret, We have several databases on the same ms sql instance. And some sql for these dabases encompass objects from several ones. So this time we should add a cloumn to a view and also update a proc in another database so that it will use this column. The problem is we should ensure that view will be updated before procedure, so that last one could be updated successfully. But with the separate logs for each database I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Order in which database are being updated (by separate changelogs) we determine in our CI configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into [Context](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html).

> “Contexts” in Liquibase are tags you can add to changeSets to control which will be executed in any particular migration run. Any string can be used for the context name and they are checked case-insensitively.
>
> When you run the migrator though any of the available methods, you can pass in a set of contexts to run. Only changeSets marked with the passed contexts will be run.

A possible solution:

1. Add `db1` context for changesets that needs to be run on first DB, and `db2` context that needs to be run on the second DB.
2. You already placed both changes into single log.
3. Now you just need to run liquibase twice. First time with context `db1` the second time with `db2`. (Second execution may depend on result of the first one.)